# Duplicate React after downloading npm package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-hooks

I have an npm package (that I published) which causes duplicate React instances and hence the following Component Exception:
"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component..."

What should I do in order to prevent this error from occurring in projects that download this package?

Comment: that doesn't sound like duplicate instances. That sounds like you are using hook in class components, and you can only use hooks in functional components. https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it is functional components. You can see the package source code [here](https://github.com/D10S60948/react-native-range-slider-expo/blob/master/src/RangeSlider.tsx). I know it's duplicated React instances as I ran `npm ls react` and saw two instances of React.

Comment: it working in this Snack I created? https://snack.expo.io/@yoobit0616/slider

Comment: I see but still - I received couple of issues (can see it in repository) so I created a new project and installed it there myself and received this exception as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the willing to help. I found out the problem. You can see my answer if you want to understand the problem as well  :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The following answer relates to **publishing** a package and not **installing**.

For future generations (and current) in case you came across with the same issue, meaning that you ran `npm ls react` and saw 2 different instances of `React`. The problem is due to the fact that `React` should be in your `package.json` under the `peerDependencied` and not under `dependencies`.

You can find a lot of info about it online but I recommend reading this [article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-publish-your-package-on-npm-7fc1f5aae600) as it simplifies the subject and makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Within a single app, React may exist in several instances** (the most probable reason):**
If you use Node for package management, you can run to check the React duplicity in your project folder:

```
npm ls react
```

to slove the issue : 1. don't use react , react-dom as dependencies or devDepenencies in your published package's package.json file, rather just mention them as peerDependencies
2.(how usually I solve this issue): mention inside the webpack.config.js file :

```
     resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react"),
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, when you create your package, dont specify any version to `react`
in dependency add `"react:": "*"`

This will mean that it will use whatever `react` version that are installed on the user project